# How to browse keys of an object

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking to get/display the key name of an object in AS3.

I have for example :

```
var obj:Object = {key:"value"};
```

Here I try to display "key" (not its value).

The goal is to be able to merge two objects together.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get at the keys of an object you need to loop over them:

```
for (var key:String in obj) {
    trace("key:", key, "value:", obj[key]);
}
```

Thus, merging `obj1` and `obj2` (with anything from the second overwriting the first) would look like this:

```
var merged:Object = {};
var key:String = "";

for (key in obj1) {
    merged[key] = obj1[key];
}

for (key in obj2) {
    merged[key] = obj2[key];
}
```

Comment: Ohhh funcky. I was doing "for each". I didn't know for(var...) existed. Thx !